# git add --patch no longer prompting to stage hunks

Tags: macos, git

Recently, when I run `git add --patch` to add changes before committing, I am no longer prompted to `Stage this hunk [y/n/a/d/K/j/J/e/?]?`

I just see a diff outputted and then am back at my prompt.

I wish I had more details about this but it has seemingly come out of nowhere and I'm not sure how to begin diagnosing it.

Git version: 2.14.2
zsh version: 5.4.2
macOS: 10.12.6

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Updating to git 2.14.3 fixed the issue for me. I'm not certain why 2.14.2 had problems on my machine.